# left join not return the all the rows from left table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I really didn't find out that why left join does not return all the rows form t1. Please any help would appreciated.

**t1 schema:**

```
 CREATE TABLE `tbl_assigned` (
     `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `Round` int(2) NOT NULL,
     `TraineeID` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
     `Name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
     `Mobile` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `BatchID` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
     `Remarks` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
     `District` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Comments` varchar(21) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Level` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Trade` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Status` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     `Photo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
     KEY `TraineeID` (`TraineeID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=356 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**t2 schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_attn_temp` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `TraineeID` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
 `ScannerID` int(7) NOT NULL,
 `attnDate` date NOT NULL,
 `attnTime` time NOT NULL,
 `Status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2135 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**query:**

```
SELECT t1.TraineeID, t2.attnDate
FROM tbl_assigned t1
LEFT JOIN tbl_attn_temp t2 on t1.TraineeID=t2.TraineeID
WHERE t1.BatchID='ID-Welding/SSTS-01M/R7/01' and t2.attnDate='2015-12-28'
```

**Output:**

```
TID   attnDate
15950 2015-12-28
24310 2015-12-28
24317 2015-12-28
24327 2015-12-28
24400 2015-12-28
24973 2015-12-28
25186 2015-12-28
25281 2015-12-28
25285 2015-12-28
25300 2015-12-28
```

but t1 table has 15 TraineeID with this criteria.

```
SELECT t1.TraineeID FROM tbl_assigned t1 WHERE t1.BatchID='ID-Welding/SSTS-01M/R7/01'
```

output:

```
15950
20012
21173
24310
24317
24327
24400
24936
24973
25033
25186
25281
25282
25285
25300

SELECT t2.TraineeID, t2.attnDate FROM tbl_attn_temp t2 WHERE t2.attnDate='2015-12-28'
```

Output:

```
ID        Date
SSTS001 2015-12-28
SSTS001 2015-12-28
SSTS001 2015-12-28
15950 2015-12-28
24317 2015-12-28
24738 2015-12-28
25186 2015-12-28
25281 2015-12-28
24973 2015-12-28
24310 2015-12-28
24400 2015-12-28
24327 2015-12-28
25300 2015-12-28
25285 2015-12-28
SSTS002 2015-12-28
28702 2015-12-28
28702 2015-12-28
22934 2015-12-28
26620 2015-12-28
24068 2015-12-28
21343 2015-12-28
1151467 2015-12-28
24931 2015-12-28
24931 2015-12-28
24931 2015-12-28
4872 2015-12-28
24071 2015-12-28
24786 2015-12-28
6203 2015-12-28
24069 2015-12-28
```

Comment: What your expected result?

Comment: Are your expected rows being filtered out by the `WHERE` clause looking for `t2.attnDate='2015-12-28'`?

Comment: The where clause will filter the results. `t1.BatchID='ID-Welding/SSTS-01M/R7/01'`

Comment: Remove condition `t1.BatchID='ID-Welding/SSTS-01M/R7/01'` then you can get your expected output

Comment: @ChrisNauroth- Yes sir, `t2.attnDate='2015-12-28'` filtered out the expected result.

Comment: @sadikhasan- Sir, that mean left join does not allow this where clause? But without join I got 15 rows from t1 table with this criteria.

Comment: Yes. Where clause is applied after the left join. I guess having `and` instead of `where` might work. I am not sure about this though.

Comment: @MirAbzalAli left join allow where clause but as per your expected result here you do not have to used/

Comment: Do one thing `SELECT t1.TraineeID FROM tbl_assigned t1 WHERE t1.BatchID='ID-Welding/SSTS-01M/R7/01'` and `SELECT t2.attnDate FROM tbl_attn_temp t2 WHERE t2.attnDate='2015-12-28'` and add this query with output in your question. So we can figure it out.

Comment: @kaushaMehta- Sir, I added the particular query output

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is issue of space in the BatchID field. Space may be in the beginning and end of missing records.

Also check date of other records as well.

To tackle with space issue which may be in the beginning and end of records

use this query.

```
SELECT t1.TraineeID, t2.attnDate
FROM tbl_assigned t1
LEFT JOIN tbl_attn_temp t2 on t1.TraineeID=t2.TraineeID
WHERE ifnull(trim(t1.BatchID),'')='ID-Welding/SSTS-01M/R7/01'
```

if you get expected records then check if date is '2015-12-28' in other records as well.

Comment: Sir, here's no issues about space, cause many other queries run with parameter and working fine. Thanks for the cooperation.

Comment: okay, If you run above query, does it give you list which includes your desired result?

Comment: well there is issue with data of BatchID field. Without required table data available, there can't be any resolution.